# How to create an XPATH for the dynamically changing properties

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

When users logs in , I can see the below html source. I'm trying to implement click operation for the "Change Password" link using Webdriver in C#.

When user 1 Login , the below sample code generates for change password link:

```
<td> <a href="../../siteagent/pw/ser.fcc?SENC=UTF-8 &TSON=34&TARGET=/uas/authaction/slogin.do&USERNAME=xxxxx@xxx.com"> <img src="/u/default/img/global/change_password.gif;jsessionid=xxxxxxxEA57DB0A9F754B53A6E" width="92" height="15" alt="Change Password" border="0"></a></td>
```

When user 2 Login , the below sample code generates for change password link:

```
<a href="../../siteagent/pw/ser.fcc?SMENC=UTF-8 &amp;TSON=34&amp;TARGET=/uas/authaction/slogin.do&amp;USERNAME=xxxxx@xxx.com">Change Password</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can you OR in xpath so that any user xpath will work:

```
//img[@alt='Change Password']|//a[contains(text(),'Change Password')]
```